# cannot find firefox binary in path

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, windows-8

I am getting error:

```
Failed: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException Cannot find firefox binary in PATH, make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be WIN8
```

I am using `Selenium v 2.30` and `Firefox v.19` on `windows 8 64bit`

same code was working perfectly on windows7/SP1.

```
if(browser == SupportedBrowser.FIREFOX) {           
           //firefox driver is built into selenium standalone server
           return new FirefoxDriver();
       }
```

Comment: Is the firefox binary in your PATH then? Check your environment variables.

Comment: Try to degrade firefox version to 18 and check if it works !

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Command line (Start -> Run -> type "cmd")
2. type `PATH`
3. Verify that you can see here written `firefox.exe` somewhere

It his does not help then change the constructor like this:

```
if(browser == SupportedBrowser.FIREFOX) { 
  File pathToBinary = new File("path/to/firefox.exe");
  FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
  FirefoxDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
  return _driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","PATH_TO_BINARY");
```